# How to find peak and valley in running sequence in sql

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

So I've got a dataset in athena, so for the purposes of this you can probably treat it as a postgres database. The a sample of the data can be seen in this [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4b3732/2).

Here's a sample:

```
  create table vals (
  timestamp int,
  type varchar(25),
  val int
  );

  insert into vals(timestamp,type, val) 
  values      (10, null, 1),
              (20, null, 2),
              (39, null, 1),
              (40,'p',1),
              (50,'p',2),
              (60,'p',1),
              (70,'v',5),
              (80,'v',6),
              (90,'v',6),
              (100,'v',3),
              (110,null,3),
              (120,'v',6),
              (130,null,3),
              (140,'p',10),
              (150,'p',8),
              (160,null,3),
              (170,'p',1),
              (180,'p',2),
              (190,'p',2),
              (200,'p',1),
              (210,null,3),
              (220,'v',1),
              (230,'v',1),
              (240,'v',3),
              (250,'v',41)
```

What I'd like to get is a dataset that includes all the values but highlights the highest value of the 'p' and the lowest value of the contiguous 'v's.

so ultimately I'd get:

```
   timestamp, type, value, is_peak
    (10, null, 1, null),
    (20, null, 2, null),
    (39, null, 1, null),
    (40,'p',1, null),
    (50,'p',2, 1),
    (60,'p',1, null),
    (70,'v',5, null),
    (80,'v',6, null),
    (90,'v',6, null),
    (100,'v',3, 1),
    (110,null,3, null),
    (120,'v',6, 1),
    (130,null,3, null),
    (140,'p',10, 1),
    (150,'p',8, null),
    (160,null,3, null),
    (170,'p',1, null),
    (180,'p',2, 1),
    (190,'p',2, null), -- either this record or 180 would be fine
    (200,'p',1, null),
    (210,null,3, null),
    (220,'v',1, 1), -- again either this or 230
    (230,'v',1, null),
    (240,'v',3, null),
    (250,'v',41, null)
```

is peak has a lot of choices for the type, if it were some sort of denserank or incrementing number that'd be fine. Just so I can be confident that within the contiguous set the 'marked' one is the highest or lowest value.

Good luck appreciate the assist

note: The peak of the max of the peaks or min of the valley's can be anwhere in the contiguous set, but as soon as the type changes we start over.

Comment: how would you like to treat the rows tied in timestamps? eg: row with timestamp 100 in the sample data

Comment: Sorry that is a typo the time stamps can be considered ascending, unique, and non contiguous

Comment: With your last edit, in your sample output for timestamp 180 and 190, when you say "either this record or 180", is it ok to have both records "marked"?

Comment: @Junjie, ideally only one would be marked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a little trick that can be used for a gaps-and-islands problem like this one.

By subtracting a row_number from a row_number over a value you get some ranking.

There's some disadvantages with this method for certain purposes.
But it works for this case.

Once that ranking is calculated then it can be used by the other window functions in the outer query.
And we can again use row_number for this. 
But depending on the requirement, you could use DENSE_RANK or the window function of MIN & MAX instead.

Then we just wrap those in  a `CASE` for the different logic depending on the type.

```
select timestamp, type, val, 
(case 
 when type = 'v' and row_number() over (partition by (rn1-rn2), type order by val, rn1) = 1 then 1
 when type = 'p' and row_number() over (partition by (rn1-rn2), type order by val desc, rn1) = 1 then 1
 end) is_peak
-- , rn1, rn2, (rn1-rn2) as rnk
from
(
  select timestamp, type, val,
   row_number() over (order by timestamp) as rn1,
   row_number() over (partition by type order by timestamp) as rn2
  from vals
) q
order by timestamp;
```

You can test a SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/929ac/6/0)

Returns:

```
timestamp   type    val     is_peak
---------   ----    ----    -------
10          null    1       null
20          null    2       null
39          null    1       null
40          p       1       null
50          p       2       1
60          p       1       null
70          v       5       null
80          v       6       null
90          v       6       null
100         v       3       1
110         null    3       null
120         v       6       1
130         null    3       null
140         p       10      1
150         p       8       null
160         null    3       null
170         p       1       null
180         p       2       1
190         p       2       null
200         p       1       null
210         null    3       null
220         v       1       1
230         v       1       null
240         v       3       null
250         v       41      null
```

Comment: sorry i'm having issues getting the sql fiddle to work, I'll try the code as soon as I can against my actual data.

Comment: dude this seems to work really well even with my new updated crazy duplicated peaks.

Comment: @NathanFeger to be honest, it works well in your case. I was wondering what to do with a null in between, For example 140 till 200 has 'p' with a null between. But your example sees them as different groups of 'p'.  There's some fancy stuff that can be used in those window functions. But it doesn't seem needed for this.

Comment: the group at 140 and the 'group' at 200 are supposed to be different groups. This example is a bit contrived. hence all the changes to the data since you made an attempt

Answer (score 3):

You could use [LEAD/LAG window functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/window.html):

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN type = 'p' AND val>LAG(val) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp)
        AND val > LEAD(val) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp) THEN 1 
       WHEN type = 'v' AND val<LAG(val) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp)
       AND val < LEAD(val) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp) THEN 1 
  END AS is_peak
FROM vals
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7e078de135df0d1c131b2a10342b1424)**

Output:

```
┌───────────┬───────┬──────┬─────────┐
│ timestamp │ type  │ val  │ is_peak │
├───────────┼───────┼──────┼─────────┤
│       10  │       │   1  │         │
│       20  │       │   2  │         │
│       39  │       │   1  │         │
│       40  │ p     │   1  │         │
│       50  │ p     │   2  │       1 │
│       60  │ p     │   1  │         │
│       70  │ v     │   5  │         │
│       80  │ v     │   6  │         │
│       90  │ v     │   6  │         │
│      100  │ v     │   3  │       1 │
│      110  │       │   3  │         │
│      120  │ v     │   6  │         │
│      130  │       │   3  │         │
│      140  │ p     │  10  │       1 │
│      150  │ p     │   8  │         │
└───────────┴───────┴──────┴─────────┘
```

---

Version with window clause:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN type = 'p' AND val > LAG(val) OVER s
                AND val > LEAD(val) OVER s THEN 1 
               WHEN type = 'v' AND val < LAG(val) OVER s
                AND val < LEAD(val) OVER s THEN 1 
          END AS is_peak
FROM vals
WINDOW s AS (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2382b585a470ef19166320b15513a3e3)**

**EDIT**

> *I think with a hopefully small change we can get timestamp 120 also, then that'll be it*

```
SELECT *,CASE
  WHEN type IN ('p','v') AND val > LAG(val,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp)
  AND val > LEAD(val,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp) THEN 1 
  WHEN type IN ('v') AND val < LAG(val,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp)
  AND val < LEAD(val,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp) THEN 1 
 END AS is_peak
FROM vals
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0794ecbc6374bd2eff7187e19b3bba48)**

---

**EDIT 2:**

Final solution with `gaps-and-islands` detection(handling plateau):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, LEAD(val,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp) AS l
  FROM vals
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN val = l THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp) AS dr
  FROM cte
), cte3 AS (
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN type IN ('p') AND val > LAG(val,1) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp)
                AND val >= LEAD(val,1) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp) THEN 1 
               WHEN type IN ('v') AND val < LAG(val,1) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp)
                AND val <= LEAD(val,1) OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY timestamp) THEN 1 
          END AS is_peak
  FROM cte2
)
SELECT timestamp, type, val,
     CASE WHEN is_peak = 1 THEN 1 
          WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte3 cx
                       WHERE cx.is_peak = 1
                         AND cx.val = cte3.val
                         AND cx.type = cte3.type
                         AND cx.dr = cte3.dr)
              THEN 1
     END is_peak
FROM cte3
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo final](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a2006e5c44495ea336a3c229dbc89811)**

Output:

```
┌────────────┬───────┬──────┬─────────┐
│ timestamp  │ type  │ val  │ is_peak │
├────────────┼───────┼──────┼─────────┤
│        10  │       │   1  │         │
│        20  │       │   2  │         │
│        39  │       │   1  │         │
│        40  │ p     │   1  │         │
│        50  │ p     │   2  │       1 │
│        60  │ p     │   1  │         │
│        70  │ v     │   5  │         │
│        80  │ v     │   6  │         │
│        90  │ v     │   6  │         │
│       100  │ v     │   3  │       1 │
│       110  │       │   3  │         │
│       120  │ v     │   6  │         │
│       130  │       │   3  │         │
│       140  │ p     │  10  │       1 │
│       150  │ p     │   8  │         │
│       160  │       │   3  │         │
│       170  │ p     │   1  │         │
│       180  │ p     │   2  │       1 │
│       190  │ p     │   2  │       1 │
│       200  │ p     │   1  │         │
│       210  │       │   3  │         │
│       220  │ v     │   1  │       1 │
│       230  │ v     │   1  │       1 │
│       240  │ v     │   3  │         │
│       250  │ v     │  41  │         │
└────────────┴───────┴──────┴─────────┘
```

---

Additional note:

ISO SQL:2016 adds pattern matching [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/pattern-matching-in-oracle-database-12cr1) for this kind of scenarios where you define regexp for peak like `PATTERN (STRT UP+ FLAT* DOWN+)` but currently it is supported only by Oracle.

Related article: [Modern SQL - match_recognize Regular Expressions Over Rows](https://modern-sql.com/feature/match_recognize)

Comment: oh man this is close, I think with a hopefully small change we can get timestamp 120 also, then that'll be it.

Comment: @NathanFeger '120' is  in 'v' so I guess you wanted only minimum value. Anyway please take a look at **[demo v_120_marked](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0794ecbc6374bd2eff7187e19b3bba48)** I added default value equal `0` and exteded type for `peak` so you get exact  case as in your example.

Comment: Wow, i event tweaked the example to add another peak: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e9c8db9580c9e351305894bcdb8568ef and it still worked. What an impressive display.

Comment: okay I @lukasz Szozda, i made one more change to your 3rd example given the possibilty of having the same peak 2x, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=153c6a58a017350f4f26836b2c897b33 . Does this seems right?

Comment: @NathanFeger Yes, your tweak from https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=153c6a58a017350f4f26836b2c897b33 looks ok. The case is that  now you extended your original question with **plateau detection**. SQL as a language has limited timeseries analysis capabilities. Please note that with `LAG/LEAD` we are moving inside 1 row moving window  and we don't know  exact size of plateau so if you wanted both 220/230 your query will be pretty complex because then you should handle three, four and more peak long.

Answer (score 1):

You could use subqueries within a `case` statement to achieve this:

```
create table #vals 
(
    [timestamp] int,
    [type] varchar(25),
    val int
);

insert into #vals ([timestamp], [type], val) 
values  (10, null, 1),
        (20, null, 2),
        (30, null, 1),
        (40,'p',1),
        (50,'p',2),
        (60,'p',1),
        (70,'v',5),
        (80,'v',6),
        (90,'v',6),
        (100,'v',3),
        (110,null,3)

select 
    r.*,
    case 
        when r.[type] = 'p' and not exists (select * from #vals c where c.[type] = r.[type] and c.val > r.val) then 1
        when r.[type] = 'v' and not exists (select * from #vals c where c.[type] = r.[type] and c.val < r.val) then 1
        else null
    end as is_peak
from #vals r

drop table #vals
```

Results:

```
/----------------------------------\
| timestamp | type | val | is_peak |
|-----------|------|-----|---------|
| 10        | NULL | 1   | NULL    |
| 20        | NULL | 2   | NULL    |
| 30        | NULL | 1   | NULL    |
| 40        | p    | 1   | NULL    |
| 50        | p    | 2   | 1       |
| 60        | p    | 1   | NULL    |
| 70        | v    | 5   | NULL    |
| 80        | v    | 6   | NULL    |
| 90        | v    | 6   | NULL    |
| 100       | v    | 3   | 1       |
| 110       | NULL | 3   | NULL    |
\----------------------------------/
```

Note: If there are multiple records with the same (peak) `val`, they would each be marked with a `1` in the `is_peak` column.

Comment: oh perhaps my dataset is insuffiicent, there will be multiple sets of peaks and valleys. I like where your head is at though.

Comment: Ok, could you update your question to elaborate on this? If there are multiple peaks or valleys, how should these be identified? Is a peak just a value which has at least one smaller value with a lower timestamp and at least one smaller value with a higher timestamp (and vice-versa for a valley)?

Comment: yeah I tried to add more sample data, which i hope shows it off better.

Comment: Ok, I think that makes more sense now and can be done with window functions - I'll update my answer when I get a minute.