# How to clean up nondistinct event logs?

Tags: sql

I'm currently working on cleaning up some very dirty server log data like the following example below:

Conditions:

- sequential order of events (1->2->3->4) with the same ID and timestamp should be grouped together under a single unique ID.
- if the next (leading) row follows the prior sequential ordering then it gets grouped under the prior row's unique_id

**current:**

| id | event | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 | 2022-08-25 12:59:00 |
| 100 | 4 | 2022-08-25 13:00:00 |
| 100 | 3 | 2022-08-25 13:00:00 |
| 100 | 0 | 2022-08-25 13:00:00 |
| 100 | 2 | 2022-08-25 13:00:00 |
| 100 | 1 | 2022-08-25 13:00:00 |
| 100 | 3 | 2022-08-25 13:01:00 |

**goal:**

| id | event | timestamp | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 | 2022-08-25 12:59:00 | 10 |
| 100 | 4 | 2022-08-25 13:00:00 | 10 |
| 100 | 0 | 2022-08-25 13:00:00 | 11 |
| 100 | 1 | 2022-08-25 13:00:00 | 11 |
| 100 | 2 | 2022-08-25 13:00:00 | 11 |
| 100 | 3 | 2022-08-25 13:00:00 | 11 |
| 100 | 3 | 2022-08-25 13:01:00 | 11 |

Is there a way to set a defined sequential order so that the end results look like goal format?

Comment: You assume we understand the rules you are applying here.  We don't.  Please explain.

Comment: The rule is that a sequential order of events with the same ID and timestamp should be grouped together under a single unique ID

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale then shouldn't the last row have a unique_id of 12?

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale - then why was the 3rd row removed -- shouldn't it have been given a unique id?

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale -- then why was the sixth row (with the 1) moved.  You don't state anything about reordering the data.  Shouldn't that trigger a new id?

Comment: I'm thinking you want something like `rank() over (partition by id, timestamp order by id, timestamp) as unique_id` but your sample expected output doesn't exactly match what you seem to be saying

Comment: A condition to the rule is that if the next id+timestamp within a second of the prior following the sequential order then it also gets grouped under that uniqud_id.

Comment: an important bit.  This is a variation on the standard peeks and valleys problem -- answered a bunch on SO.  Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761017/how-to-find-peak-and-valley-in-running-sequence-in-sql

Comment: interesting @Hogan, thanks for sharing that, very helpful. It didn't quite solve my problem but definitely gave me a few ideas.

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale -- The key is now you calculate the two columns -- that depends on your requirements.

Comment: @Hogan the solution I used was: 1) applying a sequential order based on dense_rank() partitioned on the timestamp and event order. 2) Getting the "peaks" 3) applying the same "peak" to all rows until the next "peak" 4) hashing groups of "peaks".